# Prime factors of $16k^4 +1$ mod $8$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues, quadratic-reciprocity

I need to show that for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ there exists no prime factor $p$ of $16k^4 + 1$ with $p \equiv -1 \pmod 8$. How would I approach this problem?

Comment: Hint:  if there were such a $p$  then $-1$ would be a square $\pmod p$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $16k^4 + 1 \equiv 0 \bmod p$, then $(2k)^4 \equiv -1 \bmod p$ and so $2k$ has multiplicative order $8$ mod $p$.
By Lagrange's theorem, $8$ must divide $p-1$, that is $p \equiv 1 \bmod 8$.

Comment: Thank you so much. It took me probably 45 minutes to even find that every prime factor of $16k^4 + 1$  is element of $\{-1, 1\}$  in $\mathbb{Z} / 6\mathbb{Z}$ and you came up with this on the spot!